# Is there any hadith from Shia about "the thawab of kissing children?"

Tags: hadith, shiism, children, family, kissing

The psychologists emphasize on kissing the children. In other word, according to psychologists, kissing the children has positive effects on them.

I wonder what the viewpoint of Shia is regarding this issue. Is there any hadith concerning this matter to confirm this as a beneficial practice?

Answer (score 3):

```
                                  بسم الله الرحمن الرحیم
```

Yes, there is (are) hadith(s) regarding the thawab of children kissing. The apostle of Allah (pbuh) said:

> A man told Prophet Muhammad (SAWW) I have ten sons, so far I have not
>   kissed them (at all), the prophet got too sad (that the color of his
>   face became red  ...), afterwards said: whoever not to compassionate
>   (show his/her love), hence Allah won't show his Love (don't
>   compassionate ...)
>   (ibn Shahre Ashub, Al-Manaqeb, Vol.3, Pg.384)

Imam Sadiq (a.s.) :

> Whoever kisses his child, Allah will write Thawab ... (Kafi, Vol.6,
>   Pg.49)

---

**Sources:**

- [www.tebyan.net](http://www.tebyan.net/newindex.aspx?pid=148842)
- [www.childkafel.com](http://www.childkafel.com/index.aspx?tabid=2&catid=&subcatid=&act=view&fid=379)

Comment: A child is deserving of the kiss because of simply being a child of a parent...and also because of being a believer... as there are many verses about the position of a believer before Allah and also the love between brothers in din...and even as a little kid, he/she is to be considered as a believer...